# Handle cookie expired on oauth2 OIDC

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I´m kinda new to the oauth2 world and I´m trying to implement OIDC on an angular app. I was able to configure everything and I´m already getting access tokens (login page is displayed and the redirects go ok). The problem comes when the login page stays idle for a while and the session times out, when making the POST request to /login it replies with a 302 to login again, if you login again an error is thrown.

Please let me know if this has ever happen to you or if you need more details.
I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redirecting the user back to the front-end´s base url so it can create a new session. The drawback is that the user will have to login twice. It´s not nice but it´s the only solution i found for this edge case:

```
http.sessionManagement(session -> session.invalidSessionUrl(baseUrl));
```